# (re)initialise a vector to a certain length with initial values

Tags: c++, stl, initialization

As a function argument I get a `vector<double>& vec` (an output vector, hence non-const) with unknown length and values. I want to initialise this vector to a specific length n with all zeroes.

This will work

```
vec.clear();
vec.resize( n, 0.0 );
```

And this will work as well:

```
vec.resize( n );
vec.assign( n, 0.0 );
```

Is the second more efficient (because no memory deallocation/allocation is involved)? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
std::vector<double>(n).swap(vec);
```

After this, vec is guaranteed to have size and capacity n, with all values 0.0.

Perhaps the more idiomatic way since C++11 is

```
vec.assign(n, 0.);
vec.shrink_to_fit();
```

with the second line optional. In the case where `vec` starts off with more than `n` elements, whether to call `shrink_to_fit` is a trade-off between holding onto more memory than is required vs performing a re-allocation.

Answer (score 9):

```
std::vector<double>(n).swap(vec);
```

This has the advantage of actually compacting your vector too. (In your first example, `clear()` does not guarantee to compact your vector.)

Comment: You could had that resize() doesn't shrink the vector capacity either.

Comment: True, sorry I took that for granted (since I see clear() as a special case of resize()). :-)

Comment: This is non-standard C++ - swap takes a non-const reference which won't bind to the temporary vector. Visual C++ allows this as a language extension.

Comment: Tried it, but this failed to compile, due to the reason James Hopkin indicated.

Answer (score 3):

Well let's round out the ways to do this :)

```
vec.swap(std::vector<double>(n));
std::vector<double>(n).swap(vec);
std::swap(vector<double>(n), vec);
std::swap(vec, vector<double>(n));
```

Comment: The last two don't have the desired effect, at least under the default implementation of std::swap. :-)

Comment: Actually it does :) std::swap is overloaded in vector and calls the member function. This is required by the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the code snippets that you posted do any memory deallocation, so they are roughly equal.

The swap trick that everyone else keeps posting will take longer to execute, because it will deallocate the memory originally used by the vector. This may or may not be desirable.